# isdigit() with nonzero value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am new to python as well as new to programming, what i am trying to do is , ask user to enter two integer value for that i used isdigit(), to restrict user can only input integer values, here is my code:

```
x1 = 0
x = raw_input("enter first number: ")
while not (x.isdigit()):
    x = raw_input("enter a valid number: ")
x1 = int(x)

y1 = 0
y = raw_input("enter second number for: ")
while not (y.isdigit()):
    y = raw_input("enter second non zero number: ")
y1 = int(y1)

c = x1/y1
print c
```

this program will give error if user will enter 0 in y, to resolve this problem i tried so many tricks but failed, please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: This is homework, right? see what is happening around with y1? Where does it gets its value

Comment: Dry run the code for y=0, and you will quickly know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Change the second while statement as follow:

```
while not (y.isdigit() and y != '0'):
    y = raw_input("enter second non zero number: ")
```

To prevent multiple zeros (`00`, `000`), use following:

```
while not (y.isdigit() and int(y) != 0):
    y = raw_input("enter second non zero number: ")
```

Your code has a typo:

```
y1 = int(y1)
```

Replace above line as:

```
y1 = int(y)
```

---

Unless you want result to be floored, also change `c = x1 / y1`.

```
c = float(x1) / y1
```

Comment: did you try to run the program :D

Comment: y1 = int(y1) @AnttiHaapala sorry it was my typing mistake

Comment: @falsetru...i dont know how to accept your answer...i clicked this link of accept the answer so many times